# umbraco how to extend the rich text editor

Tags: umbraco, rte

In Umbraco, is there a way to extend the RTE?

The only menus I have available to me when I am entering text are;

[image]

I need to be able to turn on the full suite of options not just those 8.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Developer section, Data Types and find "Simple RTE" (or something like that). Inside that, you can add or remove options.

There's also a tinyMceConfig.config file in the /config/ folder that you can use to configure (duh) and expand on tinyMCE functionality in general. More on that here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/tinyMceConfig/ and here: http://imulus.com/our-thoughts/extending-tinymce-in-umbraco/

Comment: I did figure it out thank you.  I was looking at the wrong place.  I was looking at Developer\DataTypes\RichTextEditor whereas I should have been looking in Developer\DataTypes\Grid TextPage